# ElasticSearch Upgrade 1.x to 6.x

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-6

We are using ElasticSearch 1.x on production for sometime now with millions of records.

We want to upgrade the version from **1.x to 6.x** as:

1. There have been multiple updates by the company and the support for older versions is discontinued.
2. 1.x does not support Kibana.

What's the best way to do it with explicit steps on data security?

Thanks!

Comment: If there is not too much data and mapping is simple, I will suggest to get a fresh installation and reindex data programmatically, keep an eye on breaking changes. Another option is to do incremental upgrades.

Comment: If there is not too much data and mapping is simple, I will suggest to get a fresh installation and reindex data programmatically, keep an eye on breaking changes. Another option is to do incremental upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently did a migration from Elasticsearch 1.5 to 6.2.

Steps, that needs to be performed:

1. Update the mappings, there are a lot of changes that happened between those 2 versions (just as an example `_all` field is disable starting from 6.0). The official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes.html) should help you here.
2. After you updated the mappings you would need another cluster set up with desired version of Elasticsearch. Also update if needed your Logstash/Kibana.
3. Enable it to access your old cluster by adding your old cluster to the `reindex.remote.whitelist` in `elasticsearch.yml`, by doing: `reindex.remote.whitelist: oldhost:9200`
4. For each index that you need to migrate, you would need to manually create a new index in your **new** сluster with updated mappings from #1
5. Reindex from remote to pull documents from the old index into the new 6.x index

Full documentation regarding this one is available here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade-remote.html